# Combine two matrices together and organize with one value then the other

Tags: c++, matrix, octave, organized

I am writhing a code in **OCTAVE**(C++) where I have 2 matrices that I want merge together. I need to have the values from the first matrix to be intersected with the values from the second matrix. I'm struggling to explain this in words, so hopefully my real world data below will help.

```
matrix_1 = [67.06582, 14.52026,  0.00000, -5.26088, -19.44268, -21.60000]
matrix_2 = [77.79444, -0.00000,  -0.61309, -10.46707, -21.60000, -20.30657]

output = [67.06582, 77.79444, 14.52026, -0.00000, 0.00000, -0.61309.......]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Octave to simply concatenate the two arrays along the first dimension (using `cat`) and then reshape the result into a row vector using `reshape`. Since Octave uses column-major ordering, it will interleave the two vectors in the result

```
reshape(cat(1, matrix_1, matrix_2), 1, [])
```

If you instead want to do this in C++, you'll need to provide some more code which gives  us more information on the data structures that hold this data.

Comment: the data in my real world problem has repeating values and do not come one after the other in numerical order. This method mixed up my values. Good shot at it though\

Comment: @HelpMePlease Well please update your question with realistic data then.

Comment: @HelpMePlease Updated with a version that removes duplicates and sorts the output

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Updated real world data is now in the question

Comment: @HelpMePlease My first solution still yields the exact result you're expecting with that data.

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT!!! I'm sorry I doubted you in. The error was on my side of the board. Thanks alot